# How to reference an unknown number of rows from another table in sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, ddl, create-table

I'm developing a system for my parents' pizzeria. I have little programming experience, I want to make a decent SQL database so it will be easier to maintain and improve when I get better at coding.

I have come up with the following so far (using db browser to help me visualize):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "client" (
        "id"    INTEGER,
        "name"  TEXT,
        "phone" TEXT,
        "neighborhood"  TEXT,
        "address"       TEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "product" (
        "id"    INTEGER,
        "type"  TEXT,
        "flavour"       TEXT,
        "ingredients"   TEXT,
        "price" REAL,
        PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

I will create a third table `"order"` and was wondering how could I reference multiple `product.id` when clients order more than one product?

Comment: you need a order header table and then an order detail table that will have a product column and can have many rows for each order.

Comment: Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.). Dozens are online free in pdf.  Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where stuck.PS What is "reference" & why do you want to do it? PS PKs, FKs & other constraints don't need to hold, be known or be declared to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook solution would be to create a mapping table to correlate between products and orders.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "orders" (
        "id"         INTEGER,
        "order_date" DATETIME,
        -- Any other columns you may need
        PRIMARY KEY("id")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "order_products" (
        "product_id" INTEGER,
        "order_id"   INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY("product_id") REFERENCES product("id"),
        FOREIGN KEY("order_id")   REFERENCES orders("id"),
        PRIMARY KEY("product_id", "order_id")
);
```

Comment: An order has one client and one or more products.  So the `order` table should have references to the other two tables.  No bridge table or mapping table is required.

Comment: Ah.  I see your point.  You can store the order header info with items like client, orderdate, order total, and only the id joining to the details to get product, productquantity, etc.  That would save space.

Answer (score 0):

Some of what you are doing is data modeling.

- Clients can have multiple orders.
- Orders can have multiple products.
- Products can have multiple ingredients.

So the `order` table may look like...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "order" (
    "OrderId"    INTEGER,
    "ClientId"   INTEGER,
    "ProductId"  INTEGER,
    "OrderDate"  DATETIME,
    "ScheduledDelivery" DATETIME,
    "ActualDelivery" DATETIME,
    "ProductQty" INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("OrderId")
);
```

You can add FOREIGN KEY constraints if you want the database to enforce referential integrity.  (Can an order have a product that is not on the `product` table?  Can someone who is not on the `client` table place an order?)

I would adjust the column names (and add a few) in `client` and `product` to make your future code clearer.

Your final question seems to be about how to design a query.  You should learn some basic SQL skills.  (From the DDL code you provided, it looks like you're well on your way.)

In SQL Server, a sample query may look like:

```
select c.ClientName
, o.OrderDate
, p.ProductType
, p.ProductFlavour
from client c
  inner join order o on o.ClientId = c.ClientId
  inner join product p on p.ProductId = o.ProductId
where o.OrderDate
```

(I've never worked with sqlite, so I don't know if there are any translation issues.)

There are plenty of books and web sites that can help you with data modeling and query design.